# Identify a film with a device that can identify non humans

Tags: story-identification, aliens

US SF film (maybe 80's). A guy starts work with a company in a new town. (Maybe he moves his family there.) He is working on a device that you look through and it will tell you if the object is non-human.

I forget the details, but in the end scenario, he points the device at his boss (I think) who looks like a (very attractive) woman but the device registers her as non-human. It's one of those "aliens among us" films,  but I would sure like to know the title.

Comment: Are you thinking of [They Live](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/They_Live), wherein the hero picks up a pair of sunglasses that expose the aliens quietly ruling us all?  Source of the single most famous quote in movie history.

Comment: http://johnnywestmusic.files.wordpress.com/2014/04/sleep1.jpg

Comment: Nope, not They Live though that's a great film!

Answer (score 7):

You're probably thinking of [*Invitation to Hell (1984)*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0087480/plotsummary?ref_=tt_stry_pl) starring Robert Urich and directed by Wes Craven.
The movie has everything you mentioned:
The beautiful villain is played by Susan Lucci
The scientist just moved his family to a seemingly perfect town.

Plot summary: It's about a scientist (Urich) who develops a space suit in the perfect town but there is something sinister going on down at the health spa.
The spacesuit can detect non human life among other things...

Comment: Wow   brilliant you got it!!

Comment: @WillS: Great! I'm glad to help. Can you mark the question as correct?

Answer (score 5):

Sounds like [They Live](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0096256/combined) - the device was a pair of sunglasses. Here's a [trailer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L86AAGZ9BBg), which makes the movie look worse than it is. Contains the classic Duke Nuke'em line:

> "I've come to chew bubble gum and kick ass, and I'm all out of bubble
>   gum."